# tf.contrib.training.HParams error in tensorflow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow2.0, chatbot

I am trying to use nmt-chatbot from https://github.com/daniel-kukiela/nmt-chatbot but while training the model with custom data I am getting the error, as I searched on google it is because in Tensorflow v2 the "contrib" module is been removed, can anyone suggest me a replacement for that part of code,

```
 return tf.contrib.training.HParams(
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

```
def create_hparams(flags):
 """Create training hparams."""
 return tf.contrib.training.HParams(
     # Data
     src=flags.src,
     tgt=flags.tgt,
     train_prefix=flags.train_prefix,
     dev_prefix=flags.dev_prefix,
     test_prefix=flags.test_prefix,
     vocab_prefix=flags.vocab_prefix,
     embed_prefix=flags.embed_prefix,
     out_dir=flags.out_dir,
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the fate of all the contrib API [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md#list-of-projects),also [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FLFJLzg7WNP6JHODX5q8BDgptKafq_slHpnHVbJIteQ/edit#gid=0).
I don't see any direct API update in the document.
However, you can still use from tensorflow plugins by

```
from tensorboard.plugins.hparams import api as hp
```

For more details you can check [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams).